# Need Horizantal Scrollbar for Listview in windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, listview

I have a listview of just one column in my winform. My requirement is.....when item/data inside listview exceeds listview capacity(width)....need to display horizantal scroll bar automatically.  I've set my listview's View property to Details. Im not even able to scroll using keyboard key's

I've tried the following

```
listview1.scrollable = true;
listview1.view=view.details;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: check this thread `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/727366/windows-forms-listview-missing-horizontal-scrollbar`

Answer (score -1):

I'Ve replaced ListView with RichtextBox. Richtextbox is embedded with horizantal scrollbar when data exceeds width of control.

To attain column header(similar to as in Listview header), i've used an button control shaped/dragged it like header to Richtextbox's width and set its view to 3D which exactly carved as Listview.

> **Note:** *ListView control is not provided with horizantal scrollbar but has vertical Scrollbar. My solution serves only if controls holds
>   only 1 column and is subjected for Display purpose. Worked like charm*